# Advantages of having endpoints as AWS Lambdas

Tags: aws-lambda

I read on one company's job ad that they're currently in a process of "building new endpoints as Lambdas" and this got me thinking.

What are the advantages of such approach? Does this work like sort of a proxy that deals with security or is there sth completely different that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

To give a brief answer, it's hard to say what it means in their case. Usually aws lambda apis are really fast to build and really easy to maintain simply because of aws lambda nature - FaaS which is function as a service.
The whole point of that is to develop fast and efficient, without thinking how back end and servers should be implemented.
Not to mention that lambda can be integrated with every other aws service, which is real power.